# How to use python date time function/ increment?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, python-datetime

I read many of the similar questions, the function is simple nested for loops used for the API, each minute I can call 5 times. So I set the range of 75 for one year data. Can you guys help me solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

## The first part is working, enter the zip code from the list.

```
for zip in zipcode: 
    url4 = url1+str(zip)+url2
```

## Second part is not working

```
for x in range (0,75):
   counter = x * 5
   startdate += datetime.timedelta(days=counter)
   enddate += datetime.timedelta(days=counter)
   url = url4+startdate+","+enddate+url3
   apifunction(url)
```

## system said：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#51>", line 3, in <module>
    startdate += datetime.timedelta(days=counter)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

Answer (score 6):

Probably you're importing like this

```
from datetime import datetime
```

This way you import `datetime` type from `datetime` module. And this type of course does not have `timedelta` type in it.

You should import like this:

```
import datetime
```

In this case you simply import `datetime` module, and when you do `datetime.timedelta` it means that you want to use type `timedelta` from module `datetime`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like datetime is getting redefined somewhere else in your code.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> type(datetime)
<type 'module'>
```

Your 'datetime' there is an object, which probably means you made a variable and called it datetime somewhere else in your code.